# jQuery mobile slider is not refreshing after transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I will try to describe the problem that I stuck with for more than a week now. Sorry in advance for long explanation and may be bad english (not native).

I have nodejs express + pug + jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 project.

I tried to get rid off all external complexity - leaving only what is needed to reproduce the problem:
https://apricot-sidecar.glitch.me - here is light-weight project example
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/apricot-sidecar - project code is here

Reproduce the problem:
so open in browser link https:// apricot-sidecar.glitch.me -> click "Buro" -> click "Home" button in top right corner -> click "Buro" again ===> slider will be refreshed each time and set up 65 as value

now open link https:// apricot-sidecar.glitch.me/rooms/1/rollos (or refresh page with sliders in browser by hands) -> click "Home" -> click "Buro" -> we come back to `rooms/1/rollos` -> but now slider is showing 0.

I set up value in `/views/rooms/rollos.pug`

```
$(document).off('pagebeforeshow', '#!{pageId}').on('pagebeforeshow','#!{pageId}', function(event, ui) {
  console.log('pagebeforeshow');
  //- QUESTION: HERE WE TRY TO SET SLIDER VALUE TO 65 EACH TIME WE LOAD THIS PAGE
  $('#Slider-4-!{pageId}').val(65).slider('refresh');
});
```

If you open browser console while making these transitions you will see that every time we load `/rooms/1/rollos` "console.log('pagebeforeshow')" is executed -> this means that all code inside this function should be executed as well. But this line "$('#Slider-4-!{pageId}').val(65).slider('refresh');" refresh slider only in first case, when we start navigation from roomlist. In second case it's not working while we still see (via console) that this block of code should be executed.

I believe that there is some stupid error in code I couldn't notice. Or may be some bug in jQuery Mobile with which only I am facing now.
Appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

P.S. if I won't write `.off('pagebeforeshow', '#!{pageId}')` in code above, then number of 'pagebeforeshow' callbacks will grow each time we make a transition.

Comment: sorry, can't understand what you mean with *EACH TIME WE LOAD THIS PAGE*...by doing that, you will loose the slider state, it would be the same as setting the default for the slider in markup: `value="65"`- but i guess you don't want that, could you please clarify? Did you tried [pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)?

Comment: Hi, @deblocker . I edit  question above to make it more clear. My problem: while block of code inside this callback is executed each time codeline "$('#Slider-4-!{pageId}').val(65).slider('refresh');" refresh slider only when we start navigation from `/`, if we start navigation from `/rooms/1/rollos`, then second time we return to this page, slider would not refresh. But we expect it to be set again to 65.

Comment: sorry, this is a logical mistake, you can't delegate to a child the management of his family. Page events are raised by the PageContainer, here is the whole story: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).

Comment: Moreover, i just noticed you have both, JQM and jQuery-UI libraries referenced in your project, this is potentially another source of issues until you know how to handle both libraries together.

Comment: @deblocker jQuery-UI was an extra dependency - I removed it from example project for now, but problem remains the same.  
Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "you can't delegate to a child the management of his family". It's not yet clear to me what should I change in code to fix the problem. Thanks for you help. I have read the article but still don't get the point. 
I also noticed that if we activate '$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;' (from the article) in 'mobileinit' event - then problem of not refreshing slider will occurs in both cases of transitions

Comment: it's about page *lifecycle*, please read this [thread](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865) carefully - IMHO you may better switch to PageContainer events, or - if you can't allow JQM to handle the page navigation - set in markup `value="65"`